# trouble accessing results array in axios get request

Tags: reactjs, typescript, api, axios

I'm trying to do a get request to the moviedb API inside of my react application. The API returns an array named results. The get request looks like this.

```
const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
const req = await axios.get(baseUrl + params);
setMovies(req);
```

Is there a way to access the results array returned by the body of the API inside req?

Comment: Sure? What is the value of `req` if you log it? Can you provide a more complete and correct code example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Well I can't provide a more complete example without showing the full URL that I'm using in the request. To help you better understand better I'm referring to the body of the API request which has a results array. As well as a page property and total_pages property. Sorry I should have said that in the question.

Comment: You can't `console.log(req)` and share the value?

Answer (score 0):

Oh never mind I figured it out.

```
const [movies, setMovies] useState<Data>([]);
const req = await axios.get(baseUrl + params);
setMovies(req);
```

Then inside of my functional component I add.

```
{movies?.results.map((movie: Movie, index: number) => {}}
```